# Android Instant Apps can be disabled in the Google Play Console?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

There is a way to disable an Instant App as developer of an app?

I want to implement it in my app just for a while to know which approach is better, AMP or an Instant App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found the solution in:

**Release management** -> **Android Instant Apps** -> **Manage production** -> **Settings** -> **Mobile holdback**

It says:

> Enter a number between 0.00 and 1.00 to determine the fraction of user traffic you want to hold back and send to mobile web. Enter 0.00 to send 0% traffic to mobile web and all traffic to instant apps and 1.00 to send 100% traffic to mobile web and none to instant apps.

Comment: “Mobile holdback” is one option. The other way is to do this in your Play Console is by redirecting all your users back to your mobile web via Play Console: Select app > Select “Release management” from left menu > “Android Instant Apps” > Select “Stop serving” > Click “Confirm”. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be just another release channel. Just like the production, beta and alpha channels, you have the same for instant apps. So once you decide you no longer want those, just remove the instant releases in your developer console.